# Get items based on the URL. The URL can end in folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

Here's my code:

```
var items = [];
var imageGalleryUrl = "https://MYSITECOLLECTION/SiteCollectionImages";

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
  var oList=    clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().getList(imageGalleryUrl);
  var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
  var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
  clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title, _Comments, FileRef)');

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
      var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
      if ((oListItem.get_item('FileRef')).match(/.[jpg|gif|png]$/i)) {
        items.push({
          'Href':oListItem.get_item('FileRef'),
          'Title':oListItem.get_item('Title'),
          'Comments':oListItem.get_item('_Comments')
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(items);
  });
});
```

By passing in `imageGalleryUrl`, it outputs an array of image files stored in that library. It will not go looking for files inside folders.

Now suppose I change the value of `imageGalleryUrl` to `"https://MYSITECOLLECTION/SiteCollectionImages/[Subfolder_1]/[Subfolder_2]"`

What would I need to change in my code so it grabs files from inside `[Subfolder_2]` only? I'm having trouble detecting if the URL is the base library or if it's a folder inside it.

Obviously, I need this to work whether the URL is the actual library URL `"https://MYSITECOLLECTION/SiteCollectionImages"` or if it's deep like `"https://MYSITECOLLECTION/SiteCollectionImages/[Subfolder_1]/[Subfolder_2]/[Subfolder_3]/[Subfolder_4]"`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! The key lies in the field `FileDirRef`.

```
var items = [];
var imageGalleryUrl = "https://MYSITECOLLECTION/SiteCollectionImages/TestFolder";

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
  var oList=    clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().getList(imageGalleryUrl);
  var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /><Value Type="Text">'+imageGalleryUrl.replace(window.location.origin,"")+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
  var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
  clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title, _Comments, FileRef, FileDirRef)');

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
      var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
      if ((oListItem.get_item('FileRef')).match(/.[jpg|gif|png]$/i)) {
        items.push({
          'Href':oListItem.get_item('FileRef'),
          'Title':oListItem.get_item('Title'),
          'Comments':oListItem.get_item('_Comments')
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(items);
  });
});
```